# How can I add a hyperlink to a javascript message?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Im trying to send an email from google sheets and I've setup the columns to represent the subject, text and email addresses. The problem is that I need to add a hyperlink in the middle of the message and im stuck here. I can't get the paragraph to format correctly AND have the hyperlink replace a word in the middle of the sentence.

This is the code:

```
function AISEMAIL() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Email Addresses');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Fields');

var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

var calendardisplayname = sheet2.getRange(2,3).getValue();
var calendarlink = sheet2.getRange(2,4).getValue();

var formdisplayname = sheet2.getRange(2,5).getValue();
var formlink = sheet2.getRange(2,6).getValue();

message=message.replace("<calendar>",calendardisplayname).replace("<form>",formdisplayname);

var n=2;
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
 let options = {
    htmlBody: message
    + '<a href="' + calendarlink + '">' + calendardisplayname + '</a>'
    + '<a href="' + formlink + '">' + formdisplayname + '</a>'

  }
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,options);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem:

- You are always trying to append the links at the end on your `options`. Also, it becomes redundant. What you need to do is include the links when you replace the values of `<calendar>` and `<form>`.

#### Code:

```
  // Add the links on the replace
  message = message
    .replace("<calendar>", '<a href="' + calendarlink + '">' + calendardisplayname + '</a>')
    .replace("<form>", '<a href="' + formlink + '">' + formdisplayname + '</a>');

  var n = 2;
  for (var i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
    var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    let options = {
      htmlBody: message
    }
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, options);
  }
```

#### Old Output:

[image: sample output1]

#### New Output:

[image: sample output2]

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but could you use `HtmlService` to create your html message?

```
function AISEMAIL() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Email Addresses');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Fields');

var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

var calendardisplayname = sheet2.getRange(2,3).getValue();
var calendarlink = sheet2.getRange(2,4).getValue();

var formdisplayname = sheet2.getRange(2,5).getValue();
var formlink = sheet2.getRange(2,6).getValue();

message=message.replace("<calendar>",calendardisplayname).replace("<form>",formdisplayname);

var n=2;
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();

//ADDED htmlText VARIABLE
var htmlText;
 let options = {

// ADDED HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
    htmlBody: htmlText = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message
    + '<a href="' + calendarlink + '">' + calendardisplayname + '</a>'
    + '<a href="' + formlink + '">' + formdisplayname + '</a>');

  }

// CHANGED message TO htmlText
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, htmlText,options);
}
}
```

**REFERENCES**
[HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)

Also, if you need to create dynamic html for each email, check out these links...

[createTemplateFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))

[.evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate())

[Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html)